# Indesign grep replace question

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

i am looking for GREP help.
I have an issue where i need to delete every line that contains [DELETELINE].

So that

```
[DELETELINE] 
TestText
Test [DELETELINE] loremipsum
Example
[DELETELINE] loremipsum
loremipsum [DELETELINE]
[DELETELINE]
```

becomes

```
TestText
Example
```

I only can get parts of it to work. Like delete the line if [DELETELINE] is in the middle or in the beginning or at the end. But i need an expression that catches all cases.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**:

What i got is this:

```
^.+\[DELETELINE\].+\r
```

But this selects only the third line.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the answer

the following grep works for all cases

```
^.*\[DELETELINE\].*(\r?|\n?)
```

^ is beginning of a paragraph
\r and \n are different types of linebreaks so everything should be catched.

Comment: With this query, if your last line must be deleted, it wouldn't be caught because there would be no vertical space at the end of it. Try .*\[DELETELINE\].*\v? in order to catch it as well. FYI \v means vertical space (it catches both \r and \n) and ? means zero or one time

Comment: Your recommendation targets every line. Also those two i don't want to touch. But the ? was a good hint. With that my solution works. + 1

Comment: Oh I see... the anti-slashes before the brackets were deleted in my comment. Just type them back ^^